# Создание и открытие sheet из standalone script

Tags: google-apps-script

Каким образом возможно открыть Google таблицу из standalone script. т.е. Он делает определенную обработку внешних данных оформляет их в таблицу, сохраняет на диск и открывает в браузере.

А в общем задача предполагает такой алгоритм.

Автоматическое отслеживание определенной корреспонденции в gmail получение из нужного письма вложенного xml обработка его и сохранение на диске.

Answer (score 1):

Открыть что-либо *в браузере* Apps Script не может в принципе, поскольку браузер - это программа на компьютере клиента, а не на сервере Google. Он может открыть таблицу для обработки, чтобы записать туда что-нибудь. Я использую для этого метод [`SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openByUrl(String)), например:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sheet.getRange(3, 4).setValue('New Mail');
```

В этом примере открывается таблица, в ней находится страница "Sheet1", и туда записывается строка 'New Mail' (в 3-й ряд, 4-й столбец).

Чтобы *создать* новую таблицу, используется метод [`SpreadsheetApp.create`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String,Integer,Integer)). Это не столь часто требуется: обычно для одного скрипта (напр., приём данных из одного источника) достаточно одной таблицы, и её проще создать вручную.